# what's the best translation for English for the following words?

Tags: translation

what is the best translation for English for the following words:

初试锋芒，渐入佳境，登堂入室，独孤求败

For badges of game achievements

Comment: talent, expert, pro, master

Answer (score 2):

1. First Shrine/First try
2. Getting better at xxx/ Getting in the flow
3. Next Level Profficiency
4. Unbeatable